# org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig Cannot instantiate

Tags: tomcat9

```
04-Mar-2021 12:16:58.180 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig Cannot instantiate an authenticator of class [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator]
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/auth/message/config/RegistrationListener
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
                at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
                at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig(ContextConfig.java:393)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:785)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5052)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1866)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.auth.message.config.RegistrationListener
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a broken installation: the class you are missing is contained in `jaspic-api.jar`.

Comment: I have the same issue Pramod reported.  I tried adding the latest tomcat-jaspic-api.jar to my tomcat/lib folder, but same result.  Is there additional configuration changes needed beyond dropping the jar file into the lib folder?

Comment: @ivan_drago: be aware that `tomcat-jaspic-api.jar` from Tomcat 9 and Tomcat 10+ contain incompatible classes (due to the `javax` -> `jakarta` migration). The correct library should already be there.