# Embedded Tomcat9x; pom.xml: Error=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/auth/message/config/RegistrationListener

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have no idea how to research this error log, as I am following a Udemy course, but the Instructor is using an older version of all dependencies I'm posting with this question. One of the main things I'm pulling my hair out about is that although the following is included in my pom file, `<failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>` I still get the following message added to the logs in the console `No global web.xml found` along with other errors. Another thing that has me pulling my hair is that the error logs references security protocols, and I wasn't aware that I had dependencies on those protocols added in this build. This will eventually be a Spring MVC application, but I am having trouble just setting up the pom file. My pom file and the error logs are below.

pom.xml
`

4.0.0

```
<groupId>academy.learnprogramming</groupId>
<artifactId>todo-list</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <spring.version>5.3.19</spring.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
    <logback.version>1.2.11</logback.version>
    <java-annotation.version>1.3.2</java-annotation.version>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <servlet-api.version>4.0.1</servlet-api.version>
    <cargo.version>1.9.10</cargo.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- spring web mvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- servlet api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logback -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- javax annotation api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>${java-annotation.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-core-container-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${cargo.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <release>${java.version}</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.10</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                    <type>embedded</type>
                </container>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

error logs

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\James.Benton\IdeaProjects\todo-list "-Dmaven.home=C:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=57351:C:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2021.2.4 org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven3-plugin:1.9.10:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------< academy.learnprogramming:todo-list >-----------------
[INFO] Building todo-list 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- cargo-maven3-plugin:1.9.10:run (default-cli) @ todo-list ---
[INFO] [en3.ContainerRunMojo] Resolved container artifact org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-core-container-tomcat:jar:1.9.10 for container tomcat9x
[INFO] [beddedLocalContainer] Tomcat 9.x Embedded starting...
May 03, 2022 11:04:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 03, 2022 11:04:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
May 03, 2022 11:04:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
May 03, 2022 11:04:50 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 03, 2022 11:04:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFO: No global web.xml found
May 03, 2022 11:04:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig authenticatorConfig
SEVERE: Cannot instantiate an authenticator of class [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/security/auth/message/config/RegistrationListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig(ContextConfig.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:997)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:788)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.addWebapp(Tomcat.java:249)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatEmbedded$Wrapper.invoke(TomcatEmbedded.java:454)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatEmbedded$Wrapper.invoke(TomcatEmbedded.java:413)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatEmbedded$Embedded.createContext(TomcatEmbedded.java:712)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedLocalDeployer.deploy(TomcatEmbeddedLocalDeployer.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedLocalDeployer.redeploy(TomcatEmbeddedLocalDeployer.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractCatalinaEmbeddedLocalContainer.doStart(AbstractCatalinaEmbeddedLocalContainer.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.AbstractEmbeddedLocalContainer.startInternal(AbstractEmbeddedLocalContainer.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.AbstractLocalContainer.start(AbstractLocalContainer.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven3.ContainerStartMojo.executeLocalContainerAction(ContainerStartMojo.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven3.ContainerRunMojo.doExecute(ContainerRunMojo.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.maven3.AbstractCargoMojo.execute(AbstractCargoMojo.java:437)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.auth.message.config.RegistrationListener
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 72 more

May 03, 2022 11:04:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig configureStart
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
May 03, 2022 11:04:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
May 03, 2022 11:04:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Warning: No org.apache.tomcat.JarScanner set in ServletContext. Falling back to default JarScanner implementation.
May 03, 2022 11:04:56 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 03, 2022 11:04:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
May 03, 2022 11:04:57 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [435] milliseconds.
May 03, 2022 11:04:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/todo-list] startup failed due to previous errors
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/C:/Users/James.Benton/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina/9.0.58/tomcat-catalina-9.0.58.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] [beddedLocalContainer] Tomcat 9.x Embedded started on port [8080]
[INFO] Press Ctrl-C to stop the container...
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing something in the Tomcat.

At least it was asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470796/org-apache-catalina-startup-contextconfig-authenticatorconfig-cannot-instantiate) and [GitHub](https://github.com/http4s/http4s/issues/639) both with the same Results. Had the problem once and adding the jar fixed the problem. Haven't tried it for a while now, but I think, that you might give it a try

Comment: I tried adding the jar file spoken of as a dependency to my pom file and even tried being specific and searching for the `javax/security/auth/message/config/RegistrationListener` dependency on the maven repository, but no luck resolving this error. One strange finding is when I switch over to eclipse, although I get the same error when running the cargo:run for the embedded tomcat, when I run the same program from the tomcat installation I've manually configured, I don't get the errors and, with the bare bones setup, my html file gets served to the browser when I append the file name. Odd?

Comment: @JTBJ - Did you ever solve this issue?  If so, what did you do?